# There are exactly $2^k$ elements $a\in R$ such that $a^2=a$.

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $p_1,\cdots,p_k$ be distinct primes, and let $n=p_1\cdots p_k$. If $R$ is the ring of integers modulo $n$, show that there are exactly $2^k$ elements $a\in R$ such that $a^2=a$.

Observation: this exercise appears on Herstein's book.

I guess this will work with induction on $k$. For $k=1$, if $a^2=a$, then $a(a-1)=0$ and since $R$ is domain, it follows that $a=0$ or $a=1$. OK

Now how can I work with induction hyphotesis? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The claim is false if one of the $p_i$ is even

Comment: @Hagen they are primes, just exclude 2

Comment: You have $n \mid a(a-1)$ and the numbers $a$ and $a-1$ are relatively prime. Each $p_i$ goes into exactly one of them.

Comment: @BadamBaplan of course, i've corrected it.

Comment: is there a reason why you are especially determined to use an inductive argument?

Comment: @BadamBaplan was just my first idea. But seeing the user's above answer, it will work fine without induction.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Why? There are two idempotents in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, four in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think induction simplifies matters here.

By Chinese remainder theorem, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong \prod\limits_{i=1}^{k} \mathbb{Z}/p_i\mathbb{Z}$

Notice that an element is idempotent in the right-hand-side product iff all of its components are idempotent.  In our product, each component is a field, which possesses precisely the idempotents $0$ and $1$.